# Get one of specific words from a text string. Excel 2016+

Tags: excel, transpose, ifs

I have a list of words I need to get from a text string:

- A cow
- Dog-boy
- Hello-get it

(just random words)

I have multiple cells with random words surrounding desired ones:

- Random wordlsads **A cow** askjdhakj
- sla;alsj **Dog-Boy** l;sasla
- skla **Hello-get it** ksalksajsa

And I need an excel function to extract my specified words from this cell. The problem is that I need 1 universal formula that checks all words in a string and returns if something matches one of the words in a list.

I would use following function to extract one word from 1 cell:

```
=TRIM(MID(D4,SEARCH(R3,D4),LEN(R3)))
```

Where **D4** is a text string I need to check and **R3** is a word I am looking for.

I was trying to combine those using IFS formula:

```
=TRIM(IFS($R$4=MID(D2,SEARCH($R$4,D2),LEN($R$4)),$R$4,$R$2=MID(D2,SEARCH($R$2,D2),LEN($R$2)),$R$2))
```

But, as some of you already get, it returns **#VALUE!** error, because when first SEARCH formula runs and does not find any match it returns **#VALUE!** error and whole function returns it, despite the fact that it could actually have 1 TRUE result.

I googled a lot and, as I understand, I need to use TRANSPOSE formula to create an array, and somehow get result from there, but, I guess, I am not that smart yet.

Would appreciate some help on this one. Thank you!

Comment: Be careful here, substrings containing a word on your list may get included returning false positives. E.g. Jack in Jacky...Etc etc. I would recommend using Regular Expressions and build an UDF to return all found words from your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Column A Houses Cells with random words with desired ones and Column C lists the desired ones then you can use:

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($C$1:$C$3,A1,1),$C$1:$C$3)`

And copy down. Adjust range `$C$1:$C$3` to suit your actual range.

**Edit**
Explanation as below.

I do not know origins of this formula. I came across this construct for the first time on MrExcel where "Aladin Akyurek" posted it.

The 2^15 part calculates to 32768 which is more (just by one number) than the maximum number of characters an Excel cell can hold theoretically i.e. 32767. It was posted somewhere by a user named "XOR LX" and I have used it since.

The construct uses `LOOKUP` function's ability to deal with Arrays and Errors enabling a fairly straightforward solution.

Comment: This one helped as well, thank you! 
Could you also clarify what does "15^2" stand for in your formula?

Comment: @SergeiFrolov I have edited my answer to include explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,C1))),1))
```

[image]

for you:

```
=INDEX(R:R,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($R$2:$R$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($R$2:$R$4,D4))),1))
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Is it that easy and I am just a dumbass? :D
Anyway, could you please clarify what does "15,7" numbers stand for. Where did you get those?

Comment: `15` returns the first match and `7` ignores errors. @SergeiFrolov

Comment: Again, that is up to the OP to declare that they are in need of that exactness.  I just answer the question as it is. @JvdV

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, I can see that. In fact, there won't be any other words in text strings, so these 2 will do the work I need properly. RegEx is not an option, as it's macOS excel I have on work and VBA is reeeeeeally slow on macOS excel when it comes to big data. But thank you for an advise as well!